# OnSelect datepicker doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

i've got a probleme with my date picker. I need to custom this datepicker but when i try to custom them it doesn't work.
Example:

I have this html code:

```
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-target="#job-date_start"  name="date_start" title="" id="datestart" class="xlarge required" readonly>
    <input type="hidden" id="job-date_start" value="" name="job[date_start]" />
</div>
```

And on javascript i try that:

```
$('#datestart').datepicker( {
    onSelect: function(date) {
        alert(date);
    },
});
```

And my problem is, when i click on a date in my datepicker the `console.log(test)` don't appear.

Thanks you

Comment: Of course you have included `jquery` and `jquery-ui` and either wait for document ready or have your code in the end of your body?

Comment: Your code works http://jsfiddle.net/m443no17/ :)

Comment: which datepicker library are  you using? If you are not using the jqueryUI one you may not get the onSelect event ...

Comment: I have included jquery and jquery-ui because my datepicker work but when i click on a date my alert don't appear

Comment: Is onSelect the only param you pass on the datepicker? If not can you include everything?

Comment: I have the same issue. Can't figure it out. If I add an `.on('change',function(){});` I can get something to happen on select but it doesn't give me direct access to the date object, which is annoying. onSelect does nothing for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse , it will work the way you wrote . But `,` is not needed if you are having only one `helper`.

```
 $('#datestart').datepicker( {
      onSelect: function(date) {
          alert(date);
    }
});
```

Hope you have imported all the libraries required for `datepicker` and ofcourse `jQuery` proper version.

`FYI` :- Your **DOM** should be ready before you are executing this script

Comment: My version on jQuery is 1.11.1. I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Inlcude jquery and jquery ui libraries and then on document ready add your code http://jsfiddle.net/m443no17/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datestart').datepicker({
        onSelect: function (date) {
            alert(date);
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes i have a DOM ready, my datepicker work, just when i click on the date my alert don't appear.

Comment: There must be another issue, because your code works in jsfiddle :)

Comment: I know but i don't know what is the another issue.

Comment: You can make a fiddle with all of your code so we can check what is causing the issue :)